# Import could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, import, pylance

I'm trying to import a bunch of flask related things. However I get the following error on almost all imports "Import could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)":

The imports are working, however the keyboard shortcuts that the imports should provide are not. I've tried switching the python interpreter to the one that is in my venv, however that does not change anything either.

I am using a virtualenv and here's a list of my installs and imports.

```
bcrypt==3.2.0
cffi==1.15.0
click==8.0.4
cryptography==36.0.1
dnspython==2.2.0
email-validator==1.1.3
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
greenlet==1.1.2
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==2.1.0
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.0
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.28
protobuf==3.19.4
pycparser==2.21
PyMySQL==1.0.2
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.31
Werkzeug==2.0.3
WTForms==3.0.1

from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import pymysql
```

Anyone know how to make VScode import correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Some modules you have imported has not been installed in your virtual environment.

And please confirm where you have installed the modules through `pip show xxx`, for example: `pip show pymysql`.